# Failed to finish project in time, now threatened with UK court

Tags: documentation, deadline, contracts

I wonder if anyone has experience and can help with some advise.

I am a programmer with 15 years of experience, and I feel it is unfair what is happening to me.

I was silly enough to sign a contract for an e-commerce project with a budget of 1500 GBP to be completed in two months. I just wanted to see if freelancing is worth a while. Now I deeply regret it.

I was paid 500 GBP in advance.
Then another 500 GBP after a month as client was happy with the progress.
Then because of the client constant changes with the project I missed the two month deadline even if I was working full time on it.
The Project is about 80% finished. The client refused to pay the remaining 500 GBP and have raised his demands that I have to complete the project or give all the money back.

To cut the story short, the client is now threatening taking this to a UK county court or small claims court unless 
1. I pay the whole 1000 GBP money back or 
2. he will pay additional 200 GBP, and I will complete the project in another month.

None of those options are attractive to me. I did all my best with the project, but I can't predict how long it will take to complete with the client changing his mind every time.

Would I be able to avoid going to court or losing it if I send all the project source and binary code up to second payment (one month of work)
or even all the code I have developed for the two months so he cannot claim he has nothing in return for his money.

I was trying to get him to agree to this option and terminate the project so he could continue with another developer. He agreed to sign first then changed his mind. I am thinking to send project anyway without signing if that helps to avoid court defeat.

I am the second developer who has problems with his project. He says he had his money back with the first one, and he feels pretty strong he will beat me as well.

I don't have experience with the legal matters though, so I don't know how strong his case is.

What should I do?

Comment: One suggestion, when just starting out, is to pursue jobs that are on a time & materials contract.  This puts more of the risk and project management responsibility onto the client.  Now when they say "We'd like to add features A, B and C", you can say, "Okay, I estimate that will require X additional hours" and the client can decide how they want to allocate their budget.  If you do take on fixed bids, the lesson is: budget for your own project management time to keep scope creep in check (and be aware that this can be a significant percentage of total project effort.)

Comment: contract is actually called 'service and NDA agreement' and was  prepared by the client with some amendments by me. I am not sure if I can disclose parts of it even if I hide some information. can I? Basically contract says client should provide all the necessary information for me, we should follow the separate Annex specification document which is very generic short and obscure as I mentioned and I have included a clause before signing which says all the amendments to the specification after signing must be agreed by both parties by a separate agreement and may incur extra charges.continued.

Comment: continued. But I did not ask for extra charges with the changes as I was hoping to finish all before the deadline. I warned him numerous times changes may threaten the deadline and cannot continue forever but I don't think I have it in writing. I think I have only couple of emails with some changes discussed and documents with changes attached to it. But most changes were discussed on Skype and not documented at all unfortunately. continued.

Comment: continued. The payment terms are as following: 500GBP before project ,another 500 after a month. last 500 after the project completion (in two months from signing) and I should handle project source and binaries after payment is received in full. Basically that's it. Not sure if helps and this makes it any clearer.

Comment: Best not disclose any more if you are subject to an NDA. The key point is the schedule containing the spec. It sounds like you mostly covered yourself, despite not signing off on a sufficiently detailed spec, but then failed to implement the controls and balances. Sadly if you signed up to delivery by a deadline and then permitted scope to creep to the extent that deadline was jeopardised without invoking your documented change management controls, you are pretty much screwed. Sorry.

Comment: If the original spec is vague, complete the project to your minimal interpretation and ask for full payment. You will be in a much stronger position if you have technically complied with the contract and the client is arguing about what the spec means, than if you have failed to meet a clear deadline

Comment: even if you have already missed the deadline. complete as best as you can. the client may well negotiate for the missing features. Don't refund unless you agreed to a refund in the contract

Comment: to Marv Mills. As I thought its bad. The best seems to return the money then. But if I return the money can he demand the code I have developed to be handled to him? Also he was threatening to charge me in court for his possible business loss for the project delay (even he has no established business yet). Not sure if those threats are realistic but still. Many thanks for comments.

Comment: I don't think this is that bad at all and a Small Claims Court in the UK is staffed with rational and reasonable people.  Since the claim is under 10,000 it will be heard in a hearing, likely at a Judge's Room.  It is extremely unlikley that a Judge will entertain any kind of non-reasonable behavior and a simple explanation of the facts will suffice.   I would personally tell the client you are firing him as a client and calling his bluff to take you to Court.

Comment: to Evan. I was thinking about this route as well. But I fear I may end up wasting even more time. 2 months if already much more that I wanted to spend. If he continues arguing about implementation it may drag further forever. If I would go this path I would need a proper contract to cover my 'back'. I wonder if there are any good template contracts that I could use if I go this route. Contract that could stand in court if needed I mean.  Any pointers? Thanks.

Comment: I can guarantee you if he says he has "beat another developer" in Court he is outright lying.  Keep every email, all threatening behaviour and maintain a diary of his actions and communications.  Calmly explain to the Judge that it is not reasonable to have to work under such punitive conditions and constant threat of legal action and you have fulfilled the contract to the best of your ability despite the client acting wholly unreasonably.  Let the chips fall where they may.  I have represented myself in Court three times; it's not scary and Judges have keen intelligence and common-sense

Comment: FYI; in the UK you are entitled to a free 30 minute consultation with a lawyer regarding any matter.  Just contact a local solicitor and ask for your initial consultation.

Comment: When I said you are screwed I did not mean you face some kind of punitive damages, I meant that you cannot show that you are completely in the right. I agree with Venture2099, the worst that can I happen is that you would be ordered to repay the money paid so far. I feel you need more help than strangers can give you online. You might want to speak to the Citizens Advice Bureau, which is a free service. Don't get too stressed over this, you are NOT going to suddenly become liable for multi-thousands costs.

Comment: to Venture. Thanks for shedding some light on the Small Claims Court. I was actually reading about it this morning and trying to understand what could happen. What I did not figure out is how much Small Claims Court will charge me for won or lost case (I mean fee for court services). If the case is 1500GBP and I will end up paying many times more that is not what I want... You say 30 minute free consultation. That may be very helpful indeed !

Comment: As far as I remember costs are not awarded in the Small Claims Court, meaning that the plaintiff *cannot* ask the judge to penalise you with costs- The total limit of your liability is the money the plaintiff says you must return to him.

Comment: Many thanks to Marv Mills, Ewan, Venture and everyone else who were so helpful today. One last question. That 30 min free lawyer consultation is it through Citizens Advice Bureau or I need to go to my local county court in England? Sorry about my ignorance with court system.

Comment: I apologize for giving offense; I won't attempt to explain my error except that I didn't mean to offend. I have deleted the comment.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace - I have removed my comment as well which was really knee jerk.

Answer (score 9):

Your first course of action should be to secure some legal counsel and get their opinion. Asking a message board for legal advice is only marginally better than doing the same for medical advice... at least in your case you only stand to lose money.

That being said, unfortunately this kind of thing is not uncommon. Customers change their minds all the time, and when it comes back to bite them will blame the project team.

The best way to deal with this kind of situation is proactively, in other words in your original contract have an statement of work and then deliver according to that. If the client wants to change the SOW that is fine, but it would be your right to amend the schedule, or the budget, or both. Remember that any changes must be documented... avoiding these kinds of misunderstandings is what rigorous change management procedures are there for.

Beyond that, the strength of your position depends on the strength of your documentation. Again we are back to the strength of your change management processes. If you just said "OK" to every change without flagging impacts to schedule, budget, quality, etc etc you are more likely to be on the hook.

If you do continue to work on this project I suggest you insist on having a full, complete, signed statement of work outlining exactly what you need to do, when it needs to be done, etc. Just don't sign on for anything that you can't do.

Comment: +1 for legal advice from the appropriate experts and +1 (if I could) about lessons learned to make a better contract and better PM processes in the future.

Comment: +1 Sound advice, particularly for the future. However right now it is all going to hinge on exactly what was stated in the contract and signed up to. Getting legal advice is a must, no arguments here, but it can be quite expensive. I'd like to see the relevant statements from the agreed contract in order to give a high level view on potential liability of the OP.

Comment: exactly what I was thinking. If I go for a legal advice I may spend even more what the project was worth, spend even more time for legal matters and even if I win it will be not a great victory. At the moment I am inclined to return the whole 1000 GBP back but I wont give him any code back so at least he wont benefit from it and he will have to start from scratch for the third time. And I will have a good lesson to remember. Wasted 2 months working for free. Cant believe how stupid I was.

Comment: That's the worst outcome- you get no money (and have wasted your time), the client gets no website (and has wasted their time). They want a website and you want some money. Before throwing the towel in I would quote them realistically how much more they would need to pay to get the finished website. You might be able to find a mutually beneficial arrangement and salvage something from it. But you'd need to be sure of the quote and therefore base it on a defined scope...

Comment: I'd agree to withhold delivery of any work product if you choose to return the money.  You do need to weigh this move against any reputation loss; the world can be quite small.  Also remember this: success is a lousy teacher.  Think of the ton of lessons learned you can capture with this experience.

Comment: +1 to lessons learned. There is nothing intrinsically bad or difficult with freelancing, you just need to learn the correct techniques for maximising your opportunity and minimising your exposure. I think you have received a good lesson in that :)

Comment: That is definitely ton of lessons learned. Initially it was all friendly and I did not realize I have to document it all to be safe. Then it all turned ugly. Its my first and hopefully last freelance project. I have worked on enterprise projects managed by proper project managers all those years. So because I have declined to return the project before we settle the new agreement I had to listen to all sorts of insults including I have stolen his money etc etc. All that was very distressing to the point I had to warn him I will take the legal action if he continues insults.

Comment: Forgot to mention. He was also threatening I will have to pay of possible loss of his business because his project was delayed. I doubt it is possible as his business is just a startup with just an idea and it would be difficult to prove business loss but you never know what may happen in court.

Comment: There is usually a clause in such contracts protecting the supplier from consequential loss (which that is) or limiting exposure. He would never in a million years be able to prove consequential loss and nor will this likely to anything other than the Small Claims Court. He just wants to scare you.

Comment: Expand your *lesson learnd* list by **claim management**.

Answer (score 2):

I was in the small claims court last month and I can tell you the Judge expects compensation for work completed.  So the other party is not in a position to claim it all back.  As for contracts, my judge formed his own opinion, even in the face of UK legislation on the table.  So a knocked up contract isn't going to be watertight.

Answer (score 1):

If you have trust in your documentation, do not fold. If you have a clear statement of work with exacting specifications and you deliver to those requirements then he doesn't have a case and is trying to scare you. Changing requirements in a project requires a statement of work addendum, really you should have made him aware of this at the start and should have started billing him as soon as he tried to change things. An important rule for the future is if it's not in the functional requirements document then it's a billable enhancement.

Get legal advice and if your documentation is solid then stay strong and don't fold.

Comment: Many thanks for the advice Chris and Doug, I fear I did not realize the importance of documentation , even if I repeatedly insisted to get proper specification he send me very short and obscure requirements. So I had to sit for hours nearly every day to discuss project on Skype to move forward.  Well lesson learnt. I will never go freelancing again.

Comment: @freelanceruk, this isn't a reason to never freelance again, just a stark lesson in the importance of clear and consistant documentation.